# use a type column or separate type table in database design?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have a category table. Each category has a type. I have 3 idea for type:

1. Use a type table and use a type_id column in category(foreign key to id of type table).
   [image: Image of idea 1]
2. Use a type table and name in type is primary key and in category typ_name(string) is primary. In this idea I don't need join for get type name.
   [image: Image of idea 2]
3. Use a type column in category and don't use a separate type table(I think it is not good).
   [image: Image of idea 3]

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. The above *looks* like a MySQL table designer, but I have removed both conflicting tags. [Edit] your question to add to correct tag and *only* the correct tag.

Comment: And which option do you think is best

Comment: Variant 3 is not an option due to possible misprints in the input. Variants 1 and 2 are safe, but variant 1 is preferred due to more compact FK expression. Also 4th variant (modified variant 3, where `type` column have ENUM datatype) is possible. PS. `integer(20)` makes no sense - in MySQL integer datatype value cannot have such amount of digits. And length specification for integer datatype is, of course, parsed - but ignored. So remove it at all and use single `integer`.

Comment: in case 1 we need join for get name of type. 1 is better or 2? @Akina

Comment: As I have said the variant 1 is preferred for me. Simply imagine that you need to alter some type name. It will be too expensive in variant 2. But this is your choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with the first option because of the following things:

- It is easier to extract data from that approach
- Data will be normalized
- You can easily distinguish between things of different category
- Easier for even a lay man to understand

Comment: thank you very much. another question is why don't second option that don't need join?

Comment: @MohammadKarimi, when you want to make a foreign key, 
The best possible thing is to use that table's id because if you have a huge database, you can some same names is different tables, but id will always be unique